# Summing non-zero bursts in a string of 0s and 1s in R

Tags: r

My data consists of a long string of 0s with some 1s in between. What I need to do is to calculate lengths of each individual burst in one the following formats.

- Example data:    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
- Expected output: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0
- Alternative:     0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Try with `rleid` i.e. `library(data.table); ave(v1, rleid(v1), FUN = function(x) c(length(x), rep(0, length(x)-1)))*v1` and the alternative is `ave(v1, rleid(v1), FUN = function(x) c(rep(0, length(x)-1), length(x)))*v1`

Comment: In the future please provide your input in reproducible form.  This tijme I have done it for you in the Note at the end of my answer.  See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This uses no packages.  `g` is the same length as input `s` but is 1 for each of the first group, 2 for each of the 2nd and so on.  Note that we use the facts thaqt the sum of a run of ones is its length and the sum of a run of zeros is zero.

```
g <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(s) != 0))  # group labels
out <- ave(s, g, FUN = function(x) replace(0*x, length(x), sum(x)))
```

giving:

```
> out
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0

> identical(out, expected)
[1] TRUE
```

The alternative is the same except we use 1 place of `length(s)` in the code.

```
alt <- ave(s, g, FUN = function(x) replace(0*x, 1, sum(x)))
```

A different way of constructing `g` which is equivalent and could be used in place of the code for `g` aboave is:

```
g <- with(rle(s), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
```

**Note:** The input `s` and expected output `expected` in reproducible form are:

```
s <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

expected <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to get the output in a single line.

```
library(data.table)
ave(v1, rleid(v1), FUN = function(x) c(length(x), rep(0, length(x)-1)))*v1
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```